# get notified whenever a certain class I don't control is instantiated in python

Tags: python

There is a class in Python that when instantiated I want to get notified of the instantiated object. This class is not under my control, and it's instantiated at times that are not under my control (and, furthermore, usually unknown to me).

I can simply do this:

```
[x for x in gc.get_objects() if isinstance(x, OtherLibraryClass)]
```

And filter out objects that I've already seen, but doing that at every point in time that I care to find the instantiations seems *really* wasteful.

Is there any way to hook into another class' constructor, it's call, etc.; to effectively decorate it such that whenever an instance appears I am notified of it (and preferably, too, with a reference to that object)?

Comment: What exactly are you doing in response to the notification, and how did you get in this situation in the first place?

Comment: Google Protobufs' Python API doesn't provide access to the underlying DescriptorPool nor does it provide references across FileDescriptors for their public/private import dependencies. I import (and call into code that imports) Python protobuf classes, and need to send these FileDescriptors as protos to another DescriptorPool to register them across a language boundary s.t. a DynamicMessage on the other side could be built from the pool. One of my most likely options to work is to just catch all the FileDescriptors (alternatively, parse the FileDescriptorProtos and use intermediate records).

Comment: ... huh... the dependencies are there, they're just not documented...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self): print "__init__" 

def k(self):
    print "Instantiating"
    p(self)

p, B.__init__ = B.__init__, k
s = B()
```

This gives you:

```
Instantiating
__init__
```

Comment: Absolutely wonderful. Didn't realize `__init__` could be reassigned just like that.